# Looking to code a gradient filled Tile in Java

Tags: java, gradient

I am designing a map that has a a river running through it for a game I'm coding. We have the code to generate said map, but the graphics portion is causing me some grief.

What I need is that when one of the squares for a "Flood Plains" tile is generated that I can use some sort of Fill to cause it to be water on oneside (or corner) and floodplains
on the other. The tile already has it's own characteristics, I'm just looking for a visual effect.

The current code I have for filling the tiles:

```
g.setColor(Color.white);

for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i += 1){
    for (int e = 0; e < map[0].length; e += 1){
        //THE COLOR WORKS
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        if (map[e][i] == 4){
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(i*10, e*10, 10, 10);
        } else if (map[e][i] == 0){
            g.setColor(Dirt);
            g.fillRect(i*10, e*10, 10, 10);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(i*10, e*10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Cyan is just a placeholder for whatever code I end up using to fill the gradient.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is map just a 2 dimensional array? Can you provide a picture of the effect you are trying to achieve? What works so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw the flood plains instead of one-coloured rectangle

```
g.setColor(Color.cyan);
g.fillRect(i*10, e*10, 10, 10);
```

I would use two triangles

```
g.setColor(Color.cyan);                             
int[] plainX = { i * 10, i * 10 + 10, i * 10 };     
int[] plainY = { e * 10, e * 10 + 10, e * 10 + 10 };
g.fillPolygon(plainX, plainY, plainX.length);       
g.setColor(Color.blue);                             
int[] waterX = { i * 10, i * 10 + 10, i * 10 + 10 };
int[] waterY = { e * 10, e * 10 + 10, e * 10 };     
g.fillPolygon(waterX, waterY, waterX.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

this would paint your cells gradient vertically.

```
   void fillGradient(Graphics graphics, int fromColor,int endColor, int x,int y,int w,int h){


        int rdif = ((fromColor<<16)&0xff - (endColor<<16) & 0xff) / h;
        int gdif = ((fromColor<<8)&0xff - (endColor<<8) & 0xff) / h;
        int bdif = ((fromColor)&0xff - (endColor) & 0xff) / h;

        int rfrom = (fromColor<<16) & 0xff;
        int gfrom = (fromColor<<8) & 0xff;
        int bfrom = (fromColor) & 0xff;

        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            int r = rfrom + rdif * i;
            int g = gfrom + gdif * i;
            int b = bfrom + bdif * i;
            int color = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            graphics.setColor(new Color(color));
            graphics.drawLine(x, y + i , x + w, y + i);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [ColorGradient](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ColorGradient.java) class back in the day... Might be helpful to you? Also, you might want to look at [java.awt.Paint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) and its subclasses, specifically TexturePaint for painting sprites